# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource on login

Tags: angularjs, web, service, token

I made a website in angular which consumes ASP.NET Web Services. I followed this tutorial: [Tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/784106/AngularJS-Token-Authentication-using-ASP-NET-Web-A).

I used the same code as there and when i make an registration it is ok and the user goes in the database but when i try to login i get that massage in the console:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load localhost:16270/token. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'localhost:50357' is therefore not allowed access.

I know the reason (i am not allowed to make CORS request) but for the register i am not allowed too but somehow the code overrides that but this doesn't work for the login. I searched google tried many things but nothing really helped. I tried to enable CORS, tried to send Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * to the response header but nothing changed. I know that i must add: Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * to the response header but how to add response header on Web Service that i didn't created (i am talking about http://localhost:16270/token). I didn't created that service and it needs header to be added to its response. How can i made that ? Or i should do something else to make the things work?

Comment: If you don't have access to the code on other domain you would have to use a proxy on your domain. Only other alternative is if the web service serves jsonp. There is nothing else you can do. Seems strange though since both are on localhost that you can't CORS enable the other one

Comment: How to add proxy on my domain ? I tried this: http://cors.io/ but it didn't work.

Comment: You set up a script on your domain that makes cURL request to other domain

Comment: Can you help me to do that. I am really new to Angular and Web Services.

Comment: should be easy to find tutorials for whatever backend framework you are using

Comment: I am using ASP.NET web services which are not written by me but i know what they look like.

Answer (score 1):

If in producation you web app and service is going to be on same domain then this issue won't be raised.

If you just want to resolved it temporary for development the you can add
access control allow origin chrome extension or you can open chrome with web-security disable by just opening a new chrome session from command prompt

```
chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C:/Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security
```